# Error "Abort signal from abort(3) (sigabrt) " for linked list in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, linked-list

The following code is for a basic circular linked list, but when one inputs a large value for n(e.g 8 digits) it throws the "abort signal from abort(3) (sigabrt)" error. I'm not sure what it means and would love some guidance about fixing this with regard to my code.
Thank you!

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

//First I created a structure for a node in a circular linked list
struct Node 
{ 
    int data; 
    struct Node *next; 
}; 

// function to create a new node
Node *newNode(int data) 
{ 
Node *temporary = new Node; 
temporary->next = temporary; 
temporary->data = data; 
return temporary; 
} 

// This function finds the last man standing in
//the game of elimination
void gameOfElimination(int m, int n) 
{ 
    //first I created a circular linked list of the size which the user inputted 
    Node *head = newNode(1); 
    Node *prev = head; 
    //this loop links the previous node to the next node, and so on.
    for (int index = 2; index <= n; index++) 
    { 
        prev->next = newNode(index); 
        prev = prev->next; 
    } 
    prev->next = head; //This connects the last and first nodes in our linked list together. 

    //when only one node is left, which is our answer:
    Node *ptr1 = head, *ptr2 = head; 
    while (ptr1->next != ptr1) 
    { 

        int count = 1; 
        while (count != m) 
        { 
            ptr2 = ptr1; 
            ptr1 = ptr1->next; 
            count++; 
        } 

        /* Remove the m-th node */
        ptr2->next = ptr1->next; 
        ptr1 = ptr2->next; 
    } 

    printf ("%d\n ", 
            ptr1->data);
} 

//main program which takes in values and calls the function:
int main() 
{ 
    int n, p;
    cin>>n>>p;
    int m=p+1;
    gameOfElimination(m, n); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SIGABRT is generally issued when there are memory issues (heap corruption being quite common). In your code, I see only the new() operator being called, but you aren't deleting any unused nodes from your linked list! Seems like you're exhausting the memory allocated to your process.

Answer (score 0):

You might be running out of memory. Check your ram usage during the execution of your program, that might lead to something.

Answer (score -2):

```
enter code here
```

````
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Node{
 public: 
  int data;
  Node *next;

};

void traverse(Node *head)
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        /* code */
        cout<<head->data<<"->";
        head = head->next;
    }
    cout<<"NULL"
}

int main()
{
     Node *head = new Node();
     Node *second = new Node();;
     Node *third = new Node();;
     Node *fourth = new Node();;
     
     head->data = 5;
     head->next = second;
     //cout<<head->data;
     second->data=10;
     second->next=third;

     third->data = 15;
     third->next = fourth;

     fourth->data = 20;
     fourth->next= NULL;

    traverse(head);

     return 0;
}```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: please add some details to help others understand your answer